# Neural network in JS does not train

Tags: javascript, neural-network

I am trying to create a simple neural network in javascript with 2 inputs, 3 hidden and 1 output neurons that use matrixes of neurons and weights to pass forward, and backpropagation training to solve XOR problem for example. The problem is I get weights always fading to 0 fast and as a result I thing outputs equal to sigmoid(0) 0.5 value or really close. I am using a sigmoid function for activation while finding neuron values like this:

```
var multyplayMatrix = (a,b) => {
    if(a.length !== b.length) return "length of matrix1 !== height of matrix2 :(";
    let c = [];
    let temp = 0;
    for(var n = 0; n < b[0].length; n++){
        for(var nn = 0; nn < a.length; nn++){
            temp = temp + (a[nn] * b[nn][n]);   
        }
        //sigmoid
    c.push(   1 / (1 + Math.exp(-temp))    );
    temp = 0;
    }
    return c;   
    }
```

After finding output from training data input I compare it with training data desired output and calculate error and weights delta with this:

```
var getError = () => {
    let predicted;
    if(desiredOutput !== undefined){
    predicted = net.neurons[net.neurons.length-1][0]    
    }else{
    return console.log("desired output not defined")
    }
    let error = predicted - desiredOutput[0];
    let weights_delta = error * (predicted * (1 - predicted));
    console.log("output error weight delta = " + weights_delta)
    propogateBackward(weights_delta);
};
```

and start backpropagating with some learning rate - My backdrop function looks like this:

```
var learningRate = 0.5;

var propogateBackward = (output_weights_delta) => {
    for(var n = 0; n < 3; n ++ ){
    net.weights[net.weights.length-(1 + n)][0] = (net.weights[net.weights.length-(1 + n)][0] - net.neurons[net.neurons.length-2][2-n]) * output_weights_delta * learningRate;

    }
    let neuronErrors = [];
    for(var n = 0; n < 3; n ++ ){
        let hiddenError = output_weights_delta * net.weights[net.weights.length-(1 + n)][0];
        let hidden_weights_delta = hiddenError * (net.neurons[net.neurons.length-2][2-n] * (1 - net.neurons[net.neurons.length-2][2-n]));
        neuronErrors.push(hidden_weights_delta);
    }

    for(var n = 0; n < 3; n++){ 
        for(var nn = 0; nn < 2; nn++){              
            net.weights[net.weights.length-(4 + nn)][n] = (net.weights[net.weights.length-(4 + nn)][0] - net.neurons[net.neurons.length-3][1-nn]) * neuronErrors[n] * learningRate;
        }   
    }
    draw();
}
```

Im using this function and XOR dataset to make a iteration/training loop like this and just after some iterations it already coverges close to 0.5

```
var train = (iterations) => {   
for(var it = 0; it < iterations;it++){  
    for(var n = 0; n < dataset.length; n++){    
        addInput(dataset[n].inputs);
        addOutput(dataset[n].outputs);
        activate();
        getError();
    }
  }
}
```

After googling most similar problems are connected with weight initiation in longer/deeper neural networks but that does not help here, and I did a couple of different variants of this net all get similar result so I'm probably loose on my theory/math..but where?:(
I'm just learning stats and this can be confusing, for me so excuse me if I didn't make 2 much sense - You can check the js live implementation here: https://codepen.io/sanchopanza/pen/MWaZJJe